# Your account does not have permission to create Developer ID Application certificates

Tags: xcode, macos

Can anyone help me with the following error message?

[image]

I have seen a few of these messages in Xcode (and on Stackoverflow) but not exactly this one. I have an admin role (but I am not the account holder). Does anyone know why Xcode has problems with the creation of the Developer ID Application certificate?

In Xcode I signed in with the admin account but still no success. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on this is pretty clear from this chart (see https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/):

[image]

You are not the account holder so you do not have the ability to create Developer ID certificates. The Account Holder must create them. The certificate belongs to the team as a whole so you will be able to use it.